# MySQL + PHP: How to handle Umlauts in Stored Procedure Params?

Tags: php, mysql, encode

I have this function in PHP:

```
public function getData($data) {
    echo $data; //param still right for example: Schärding
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, "CALL sp_kampagne_findcurrent ('".$data."')") or die(mysqli_error($this->conn));
    @mysqli_next_result($this->conn);
    return $result;
}
```

As you can see I pass the parameter `$data` to my SP and then I return the result.

The Problem here is that if I pass words **without** Umlauts (`ä,ö,ü`) it works perfect, but if im using words like "Schärding" it returns zero data, even if there is data stored in MySQL.

The weird thing is, if Im calling my SP **directly** in `PHPmyAdmin` **it works** with the Word "Schärding". So the error must be on PHP Client Side.

If you need some more Information just say it Ill try to add more.

Comment: Your db is encoded with utf-8?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @Alberto its  utf8_general_ci

Comment: use `stored procedures` rather than opening your code to sql injection with embedded vars

Comment: @RamRaider what you mean? More details pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try adding

`mysqli_set_charset` to your code, once a mysqli connection is established

For example:

```
mysqli_set_charset($this->conn,"utf8");
```

Of course updating the encoding so it fits what you need

Comment: I did just this. And it worked. Thanks man you show what StackOverflow should be. No toxic. Not duplicated things. Just the answer and the solution. Perfect.