# retrieving data from MySQL database with Persian characters

Tags: javascript, php

I have a problem with retrieving my data back from msql database when I passed my where condition value by javascript to a php side code.
here is my code:

```
$sql="SELECT ItemPrice FROM wp_my_Items WHERE ItemName = '".$q."'";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
      echo $row[0];
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
else
     echo "not found";
```

Comment: _"I have a problem"_ - can you please specify _what_ your problem exactly is?

Comment: also note, that your query is vulnerable to SQL-Injection. Switch to [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL + PHP: How to handle Umlauts in Stored Procedure Params?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144770/mysql-php-how-to-handle-umlauts-in-stored-procedure-params)

Comment: ItemName is an string in Persian format and I got it by $_GET from another form. The result that the query give to me is nothing but it is not.

Comment: I added this code and is solved.
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");